# Angular 6. fxLayout colum no surte efecto

Tags: angular, flex

Estoy intentando que el item1 ocupe el 50% de la altura del contenedor rojo, y que el item 2 ocupe el otro 50% de altura restante del contendor rojo, si esto funcionara quedaría todo el fondo rojo ocultado pero no es así.

```js
<div style="height: 300px; background-color: red">
<div fxLayout="column" >
  <div  fxFlex="50" style="background-color: blue">Item 1</div>  
  <div  fxFlex="50" style="background-color: yellow">Item 2</div>  
</div>
</div>
```

Esto es lo que yo quiero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esto es lo que obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Puede alguien corregir mi código?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es por el div superior, quítalo y agrega style en el segundo debe quedar asi:

```
<div fxLayout="column" style="height: 300px; background-color: red">
  <div fxFlex="50" style="background-color: blue">Item 1</div>  
  <div fxFlex="50" style="background-color: yellow">Item 2</div>  
</div>
```